# How to load millions of records from source to destination SQL table on daily basis when we have no incremental column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-modeling

I have a procedure which fetches data from multiple live tables based on joins and load final data into a single table but it slow down the livedb.
So i replicate the same procedure on our staging db and created all 25 tables and loading full data through ssis on daily basis but there are few tables which are huge and don't have incremental column.
For eg. I have modified date in 6 tables and not in another 19 tables so how can I load data incrementally on daily basis in all of these tables and after that i can run stored proc

Comment: Unless you can get the data from the same source the main table is, you would need some sort of column to help identify the new records in your main table, otherwise you will need to pull everything. I assume you would not want to run a check on the stage table to the main table to compare and see what you dont have yet for each of those tables and only pull that. as you already mentioned it is slowing down things. thus as per the first answer on change tracking or CDC, you would need something like that on the tables which is another way in stead of using a column to identify change.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn on Change Tracking or Change Data Capture.  See [Track Data Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).